# Show that f is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a closed surjective map such that $f^{-1}(${y}$)$ is compact for every $y\in Y$. Show that $f$ is continuous.

I think I should prove that $f^{-1}(U)$ is closed for every $U$ closed in $Y$, but I don't know how to use $f^{-1}(${y}$)$ is compact for every $y\in Y$.

Can anybody provide me a hint? Thank you.

Comment: We know that $f$ is continuous iff $f^{-1}$ is closed, but I am not sure it can help..uhm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated, this is false. Consider $f:[0,2)\to[0,1)\cup[2,3)$ defined by $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x;&x\in[0,1),\\x+1;&x\in[1,2).\end{cases}$$ Then $f$ is clearly discontinuous and bijective. Preimages of singletons are singletons and therefore compact. Finally, the inverse $f^{-1}:[0,1)\cup[2,3)\to[0,2)$ of $f$ is continuous, so $f$ is closed. We conclude that $f$ is a counterexample to the claim.